# add a div to another div using appendchild

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

I am making change to this existing wordpress theme. 
I am trying to move a div in the footer  to body. 
this is what I wrote using appendchild, but it seems not working.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("td-post-author-name")[0].setAttribute("id", "block-under-title");
    document.getElementsByClassName("td-post-small-box")[0].setAttribute("id", "real-author-name");
    var changeName = document.getElementsById("real-author-name");
    document.getElementById("block-under-title").appendChild(changeName);
}


window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();

};
```

Comment: You have a typo, there is no method getElementsById, change it to be getElementById and it will work fine (line 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, there is no method getElementsById, change it to be getElementById and it will work fine (line 4)

Comment: Thanks, that is the problem !!!!!!!!